# How to force three lists to have the same length in Python 3.7?

Tags: python-3.x, list

My function  takes three lists as arguments. Then, it uses PrettyTable to make a table, with each list being a separate column.

My problem is, that those lists are not always of equal length, and PrettyTable wants them equal.

I wonder how to append some empty positions to the two of the shorter lists, so they are of equal length.

Alternatively... is there a table-making tool, that doesn't want all columns of equal length?

Comment: Please show us your lists and your code. This helps us better understand your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use these functions:

```py
def padlist(lst, size, defvalue=None):
    if len(lst) < size:
        lst.extend([defvalue] * (size - len(lst)))

def padlists(lsts, defvalue=None):
    size = max(len(lst) for lst in lsts)
    for lst in lsts:
        padlist(lst, size, defvalue)

# Demo
lsts = [
    ["a", "b", "c"],
    ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
    ["a", "b"],
]

padlists(lsts, "")  # provide the value to pad with

print(lsts)  # shorter lists are padded with blanks
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `zip_longest`.

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def pad(*lists, padding=None):
    padded = [[] for _ in lists]

    for lst in zip_longest(*lists, fillvalue=padding):
        for i, elem in enumerate(lst):
            padded[i].append(elem)

    return padded

test1 = [1, 2]
test2 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
test3 = [1, 2, 5, 8]

test1, test2, test3 = pad(test1, test2, test3)
print(test1, test2, test3)
```

This works with any amount of lists. `zip_longest` combines a variable amount of iterables into a single iterable padded to the length of the longest iterable.